# Outlook 2010 SP1 & Gmail Problem

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, exchange

I have always had my mail setup like this.

Main account is a work Exchange Mail Box
Second account is a personal gmail account.
I always had it configured so that mail received from account 2 (gmail) was delivered into the exchange mail box. This allows it to sync the entire mail set between computers, access it from exchange webmail and most importantly only have one inbox / sent items etc.

Additionally when configured this way, when sending a mail, underneath the send button you would get to pick which account your sending from.

But I cant configure this using Outlook 2010. I dont know why. I used to be able to select to deliver the mail into the exchange box. But now I can pick a pst, but if I pick the Exchange ost, it says its not a valid pst.

I would really love to continue to run it like this, can someone assist me as to why this is no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out.

1. Setup your exchange mailbox as normal
2. Add your secondary pop account, create a new pst
3. Then change the delivery location afterwards, by clicking Change Folder in account options. This will allow you to select the exchange Inbox and thus have your mail delivered into the Exchange ost

This will enable you to have it synced everywhere and appear on your phone, without having multiple inboxes / programs to access them.

Comment: and then delete the pst it created, its not needed.

Answer (score 0):

An OST is not a PST. They are not the same in file structure or function. An OST is ONLY for the cached copy of Exchange data. You cannot read it or use it the way you would a PST.

Create a new PST and use it.

Comment: I want all mail delivered into the exchange folders which is an ost. Creating a new PST wont do this, that hasn't answered the question.

Comment: @Dale Fraser A regular Exchange account (unless it is setup to use IMAP or POP3, which is unusual) does not use a PST, and I quote you: "But now I can pick a pst, but if I pick the Exchange ost, it says its not a valid pst." It also does not need an OST. Mail is not technically delivered to an OST. An OST is just a cached copy of the mailbox, which is always held on the Exchange Server. I am not really sure what you are talking about since you are not really describing it correctly somehow. You can now add screenshots to your question. Add some of your profile settings, and explain again.

Comment: Older versions of Outlook, including early 2010 would allow me to setup a pop account to gmail and have the messages delivered into my Exchange folders. I cant see how to do that with 2010 SP1. I cant really screen shot what I used to do, I dont have access to a old system.